A Question about the Product of the Slopes of Two Line Segments within a Hyperbola
Previously I have done a problem about the product of the slopes of two line segments within an $\textbf{ellipse}$, and I have posted here: Previous Post.
Before you read this current post, you can first read the previous post to roughly know what we will do. This time I am trying to find similar property for a $\textbf{hyperbola}$, and I have done it through two $\textbf{analytic}$ ways: $(1)$ Brutal Computation with Slope $k$ of the Straight Line; $(2)$ Through Polar Equation of a hyperbola centered the right focus.
I will post these two analytic solutions below, and I expect someone can offer more solutions, especially those through geometric/optical properties.


$\textbf{Question for this hyperbola:}$ Suppose there is a hyperbola as is shown in the picture above, with $OA = OB=a>0$, $F_1, F_2$ being its two foci, $OF_1 = OF_2 = c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} > 0$ for some $a>0, b>0$. And there is a straight line crossing $F_2$ with its slope being $k $ and intersecting with the hyperbola, $E_1, E_2$ being their intersection points. Let $E_1$ be $(x_1, y_1)$ and $E_2$ be $(x_2,y_2)$. Then let the slope of $E_1 B$ be $k_1$ and that of $E_2 B$ be $k_2$. Prove that $k_1 k_2$ is determined only by $a$ and $b$.

$\textbf{Analytic Solution 1:}$
$\textbf{Case 1: $k \neq 0$ and $k \neq \infty$}$
Given that the slope of the straight line is $k$ and we have $F_2: (\sqrt{a^2 - b^2},0)$, we have the function of this straight line is
\begin{equation} y = k(x - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}) \tag{7.1.1} \end{equation}
And given the information about the ellipse in the question, we have the function for the ellipse is
\begin{equation} \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \tag{7.1.2} \end{equation}
which is equivalent to
\begin{equation} b^2 x^2 - a^2 y^2 = a^2 b^2 \tag{7.1.3} \end{equation}
And then, combining $(7.1.1)$ and $(7.1.3)$ together, we have
$$\begin{cases}
   y = k(x - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2})\\
   \\
   b^2 x^2 - a^2 y^2 = a^2 b^2
   \end{cases}$$
$$\begin{aligned}   &\Rightarrow b^2 x^2 - a^2 k^2 (x - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2})^2 = a^2 b^2\\
                    &\Rightarrow (b^2 - a^2 k^2) x^2 + 2a^2 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} x - [a^2 k^2(a^2+b^2) + a^2 b^2] = 0 \\
                    &\Rightarrow  \begin{cases}
                                  x_1 x_2 = -\frac{a^2 k^2(a^2+b^2) + a^2 b^2}{b^2 - a^2 k^2} \\
                                    \\
                                  x_1 + x_2 = -\frac{2 a^2 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{b^2 - a^2 k^2}
                                  \end{cases}                      
\end{aligned}$$
So we get
\begin{equation}x_1 x_2 = -\frac{a^2 k^2(a^2+b^2) + a^2b^2}{ b^2 - a^2 k^2} = \frac{a^2 k^2(a^2+b^2) + a^2b^2}{ a^2 k^2 - b^2}\tag{7.1.4} \end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}x_1 + x_2 = -\frac{2 a^2 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{b^2 - a^2 k^2} = \frac{2 a^2 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{a^2 k^2 - b^2}\tag{7.1.5} \end{equation}
And then since we have $E_1: (x_1, y_1), E_2: (x_2, y_2), B: (a, 0)$, we get
$$\begin{aligned}
                k_1 k_2 &= \frac{y_1}{x_1 - a} \frac{y_2}{x_2 - a}\\
                        &= k^2 \frac{(x_1 - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2})(x_2 - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2})}{x_1 x_2 - a(x_1 + x_2) + a^2}\\
                        &=  k^2 \frac{x_1 x_2 - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}(x_1 + x_2) + (a^2 + b^2)}{x_1 x_2 - a(x_1 + x_2) + a^2} 
\end{aligned}$$
This means
\begin{equation} k_1 k_2 =  k^2 \frac{x_1 x_2 - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}(x_1 + x_2) + (a^2 + b^2)}{x_1 x_2 - a(x_1 + x_2) + a^2} \tag{7.1.6} \end{equation}
Then we plug $(7.1.4)$ and $(7.1.5)$ into $(7.1.6)$, and we get
$$\begin{aligned}
k_1 k_2 
&=  k^2 \frac{x_1 x_2 - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}(x_1 + x_2) + (a^2 + b^2)}{x_1 x_2 - a(x_1 + x_2) + a^2} \\
&=  k^2 \frac{\frac{a^2 k^2(a^2+b^2) + a^2b^2}{ a^2 k^2 - b^2} - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\frac{2 a^2 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{a^2 k^2 - b^2} + \frac{(a^2 + b^2)( a^2 k^2 - b^2)}{ a^2 k^2 - b^2}}{\frac{a^2 k^2(a^2+b^2) + a^2b^2}{ a^2 k^2 - b^2} - a\frac{2 a^2 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{a^2 k^2 - b^2} + \frac{a^2( a^2 k^2 - b^2)}{ a^2 k^2 - b^2}} \\
&= k^2 \frac{a^2 k^2(a^2+b^2) + a^2b^2 - 2 a^2 k^2(a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 + b^2)( a^2 k^2 - b^2) }{a^2 k^2(a^2+b^2) + a^2b^2 - 2 a^3 k^2 \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} + a^2( a^2 k^2 - b^2)} \\
&= k^2 \frac{-b^4}{k^2(2a^4 - 2a^3 \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}  + a^2 b^2)} \\
&= \frac{-b^4}{a^2 (2a^2 - 2a \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}  + b^2)} \\
&= \frac{-b^4}{a^2 (\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}- a)^2} \\
&= \frac{-(c^2 - a^2)^2}{a^2 (c- a)^2} \\
&= \frac{-(c + a)^2}{a^2} \\
&= -(e+1)^2
\end{aligned}$$
$\textbf{Case 2: $k=0$} $
In this case, the straight line is $x-$axis, and we have either $E_1, B$ become the same point or $E_2, B$ become the same point, and this means one of $k_1, k_2$ doesn't exist, and therefore $k_1 k_2$ doesn't exist.
$\textbf{Case 3: $k=\infty $} $
In this case, the straight line crossing $F_2$ is perpendicular to $x-$axis, so we have
$$\begin{cases}
              b^2 x^2 - a^2 y^2 = a^2 b^2 \\
                                          \\
              x = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}
  \end{cases}$$
$$\begin{aligned} 
                &\Rightarrow y^2 = \frac{b^4}{a^2}\\
                &\Rightarrow y = \pm \frac{b^2}{a}
  \end{aligned}$$
So without loss of generality, we set $E_1: (\sqrt{a^2+b^2}, \frac{b^2}{a}), E_2: (\sqrt{a^2+b^2}, \frac{-b^2}{a})$. Therefore, we have
$$\begin{aligned} 
                    k_1 k_2 &= \frac{\frac{b^2}{a} - 0}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2} - a} \frac{\frac{-b^2}{a} - 0}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2} - a}\\
                            &= \frac{-b^4}{a^2 (\sqrt{a^2+b^2} - a)^2} \\
                            &= -(e+1)^2
  \end{aligned}$$
$\textbf{Conclusion}$
Hence, combining three cases together, we have
$$k_1 k_2 = \begin{cases}
                          -(1+e)^2, k \neq 0 \\
                            \\
                         N/A, k = 0 
              \end{cases}$$
Since $e$ is only determined by $a$ and $b$, we can conclude that $k_1 k_2$ is also only determined by $a$ and $b$.

$\textbf{Analytic Solution 2:}$
First, we need to show the polar equation of the right half of the hyperbola.

Let $l: x = \frac{a^2}{c}$ be the right directrix of this hyperbola with $D$ its intersection point with $x-$axis, and $C,E$ be s.t. $PC \bot l, PE \bot x-$axis with $C$ on $l$ and $E$ on $x-$axis.
For the right half of this hyperbola, by definition through the right directrix, we have
$$\frac{c}{a} = e = \frac{F_2 P}{PC} = \frac{r}{F_2 E + F_2 D} = \frac{r}{r \cos(\theta) + c - \frac{a^2}{c}}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
&\Rightarrow r = er \cos(\theta) + \frac{c^2}{a}-a \\
&\Rightarrow r = \frac{a(e^2-1)}{1 - e \cos(\theta)} \\
&\Rightarrow r = \frac{p}{1 - e \cos(\theta)}
\end{aligned}$$
So the polar equation for the right half of this hyperbola is
\begin{equation} \frac{p}{1 - e \cos(\theta)} \tag{8.1.2.1}\end{equation}
Similarly, for the left half of this hyperbola, we have
\begin{equation} \frac{-p}{1 + e \cos(\theta)} \tag{8.1.2.2}\end{equation}
Then, we start the proof through polar equation.
From $(8.1.2.1)$ we have the polar equation of the right half of hyperbola
$$ r(\theta) = \frac{p}{1-e \cos(\theta)}         $$
so the coordinates of $E_1,E_2,B$ are
$$\begin{aligned}
&E_1: r(\theta) \cdot (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)) = (\frac{p}{1-e \cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta), \frac{p}{1-e \cos(\theta)} \sin(\theta))\\
\\
&E_2: r(\theta+\pi) \cdot (\cos(\theta+\pi), \sin(\theta+\pi)) = (\frac{-p}{1+e \cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta), \frac{-p}{1+e \cos(\theta)} \sin(\theta))\\
\\
&B: r(\pi) \cdot (\cos(\pi), \sin(\pi)) = (\frac{-p}{1+e}, 0)
\end{aligned}$$
and therefore we have
$$\begin{aligned}
k_1 
&=  \frac{\frac{p}{1-e \cos(\theta)} \sin(\theta)}{\frac{p}{1-e \cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta)+\frac{p}{1+e}} \\
&= \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta) + \frac{1-e\cos(\theta)}{1+e}} \\
&= \frac{(1+e)\sin(\theta)}{1 + \cos(\theta) }
\end{aligned}$$
and similarly
$$k_2 = \frac{-(1+e)\sin(\theta)}{1 - \cos(\theta) }$$
Hence, we have
\begin{equation} k_1 k_2 = \frac{(1+e)\sin(\theta)}{1 + \cos(\theta) } \frac{-(1+e)\sin(\theta)}{1 - \cos(\theta) } = -(1+e)^2 \frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{1-\cos^2(\theta)} = -(1+e)^2 \tag{8.2.1}\end{equation}
$\textbf{Conclusion}$
Since $e$ is only determined by $a$ and $b$, we can conclude that $k_1 k_2$ is also only determined by $a$ and $b$.

Now I have finished presenting two solutions to this problem. Hope more people can offer interesting solutions to it. Thanks!

The property presented here, as well as the one in your previous post about an ellipse, is valid for any line $E_1E_2$ intersecting the major axis at ANY fixed point, NOT NECESSARILY AT A FOCUS. This is apparent from the solutions to the previous post and you can check it with GeoGebra for a hyperbola too.

Thanks for your comment here! I will check whether it is true for all points on the major axis.

Moreover, Blue's answer to your previous question also works here, because it considered a generic conic.

Here is a relatively general approach covering all the usual conic sections.
We start with the special case of a circle.
Lemma. Fix a line parallel to the $x$ axis, a circle with center on that line, a point $B$ at an intersection of the circle and the line, and a point $E$ on the same line distinct from $B$.
Then if $E_1,E_2$ are distinct points on the circle collinear with $E$, the product of the slopes of the lines $BE_1$ and $BE_2$ is independent of the choice of $E_1$ and $E_2$.
This is proved here for the case where $E$ is inside the circle. A summary of this proof adapted to all cases is as follows:
    


In the case $E = A$, the product of the tangents is a constant zero.
In the other three cases, label the angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ as shown in the diagram appropriate to that case.
In each case $\alpha$ is half the arc $AE_1$, $\delta$ is half the arc $BE_1$, $\beta$ is half the arc $AE_2$, and $\gamma$ is half the arc $BE_2$;
therefore $\alpha+\delta$ and $\beta+\gamma$ are right angles,
$\sin\delta=\cos\alpha$, and $\sin\gamma=\cos\beta$.
But also by the Law of Sines (which works for exterior angles of a triangle as well as interior angles)
applied to triangles $\triangle BEE_1$ and $\triangle BEE_2$,
$$\frac{EE_1}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{BE}{\sin\gamma}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{EE_2}{\sin\beta}=\frac{BE}{\sin\delta}$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{EE_1\cdot EE_2}{BE^2} = \frac{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{\sin\delta\sin\gamma}
 = \frac{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha\cos\beta}
 = \tan\alpha\tan\beta,
$$
which is the magnitude of the product of the slopes of $EE_1$ and $EE_2$. But by the power of a point, $EE_1\cdot EE_2 = AE\cdot BE$,
which is a constant. So $\tan\alpha\tan\beta$ is a constant for fixed $E$.
Moreover the sign of the product of the slopes depends only on whether $E$ is inside or outside the circle.
Therefore the product of the the slopes of $EE_1$ and $EE_2$ is a constant for fixed $E$, QED.
Theorem. Fix a line parallel to the $x$ axis, a conic section $\gamma$ for which the same line is a major, a point $B$ at an intersection of $\gamma$ and the same line, and a point $E$ distinct from $B$ also on the same line.
Then if $E_1,E_2$ are distinct points on $\gamma$ collinear with $E$, the product of the slopes of the lines $BE_1$ and $BE_2$ is independent of the choice of $E_1$ and $E_2$.
A conic section is a figure that can be produced by the intersection of a right circular cone and a plane. For a given conic section $\gamma$ in plane $\pi_1$, let $O$ be the apex of a right circular cone $S_0$ that produces $\gamma$ when intersected by $\pi_1$. Let $\lambda_0$ be the axis of the cone $S_0$.
The case where $\gamma$ is a circle is proved in the lemma.
So assume $\gamma$ is not a circle. Therefore the axis $\lambda_0$ is not perpendicular to the plane $\pi_1$. Let $\lambda_1$ be the orthogonal projection of $\lambda_0$ on plane $\pi_1$. Then $\lambda_1$ is an axis of the conic section $\gamma$.
Let $B$ be an intersection of $\lambda_1$ and $\gamma$, that is, $B$ is a vertex of the conic section $\gamma$.
Let $\pi_2$ be a plane through $B$ orthogonal to $\lambda_0$. Let $\gamma_2$ be the intersection of the right circular cone $S_0$ and $\pi_2$.
Then $\gamma_2$ is a circle and the central projection through $O$ of the conic section's axis $\lambda_1$ onto $\pi_2$ is a line, let's call it $\lambda_2$, that coincides with a diameter of the circle $\gamma_2$.
Now here's the key step in this argument.
Let $\mu_1$ be any line through $B$ in plane $\pi_1$ not perpendicular to $\lambda_1$, and $\theta_1$ be the acute angle between $\mu_1$ and $\lambda_1$.
Let $\mu_2$ be the central projection (through $O$) of $\mu_1$ onto $\pi_2$ making angle $\theta_2$ with $\lambda_2$. Then the ratio of
$\tan\theta_2$ to $\tan\theta_1$ is independent of the choice of $\mu_1$.
To prove this, consider a fixed line $\nu_1$ in $\pi_1$ perpendicular to $\lambda_1$ and the central projection of that line onto $\pi_2$, which is a line $\nu_2$ perpendicular to $\lambda_2$.
Then the right triangle formed by $\lambda_1,\mu_1,\nu_1$ projects onto a right triangle formed by $\lambda_2,\mu_2,\nu_2$; one leg of each triangle has a fixed length independent of $\mu_1$, while the leg along $\nu_2$ is a fixed multiple of the leg along $\nu_1$ regardless of $\mu_1$.
So let $r = \dfrac{\tan\theta_2}{\tan\theta_1}$.
Now consider a point $E$ other than $B$ on $\lambda_1$, the axis of the conic section $\gamma$. Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be any distinct points on $\gamma$ collinear with $E$.
Then $E$ projects onto $E'$, a point on the same diameter of circle $\gamma_2$ as $B$,
while $E_1$ and $E_2$ project to distinct points $E_1'$ and $E_2'$ on the circle $\gamma_2$ such that $E',E_1',E_2'$ are collinear.
Therefore the product of the tangents of the angle between $BE_1'$ and $BE'$ and the angle between $BE_2'$ and $BE'$ is a constant $k$ independent of the choice of $E_1$ on $\gamma$.
But the product of the tangents  of the angle between $BE_1$ and $BE$ and the angle between $BE_2$ and $BE$ is therefore a constant $k/r^2$, QED.
This covers the cases of a hyperbola, an ellipse, a parabola, and a circle.
Note that the point $E$ need not be "inside" the conic section. It merely needs to be on the major axis and not at the vertex $B$ (where one of the slopes would not be defined).
